# Regex with multiple lookarounds behaving differently when used with fixed width quantifier or a +

Tags: .net, regex

Regex 1

```
([0-9])\1{2}(?<=\1)(?=\1)
```

Regex 2

```
([0-9])\1+(?<=\1)(?=\1)
```

My input is "43335".

I had an idea why I needed this, but as I was playing around with it, I noticed something strange.

I have a pretty goof understanding why the `Regex 2` matches, but I absolutely can not understand why the `Regex1` fails.

The difference in behaviour begins when the regex enters the negative lookahead `(?=\1)`

1. In case of `Regex 2` it sees that 5 is not equal to 3 and thus the position is stepped back(1 step) and the first lookaround is entered again `(?<=\1)`
2. In case of `Regex 1` it sees that 5 is not equal to 3 and the position is stepped all the way back to the beginning of the string for some reason.

Could you please help me understand why this happens?

Comment: Please do not use HTML here. The Enter key works fine for a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex #1:

1. Look at the first character, is it a digit? Yes, it's a 4.  Put the 4 into capture group 1. Now look at the next character.  Is it a 4. No, it's a 3.  No match. Move on to character #2.
2. Look at the 2nd character, is it a digit? Yes, it's a 3.  Put 3 into capture group 1.  Are the next 2 characters also a 3? Yes, keep going.  Now start the lookahead.  Is it a 3 also? Ooh, no, it's a 5. This one fails too.
3. Look at the 3rd character. Is it a digit? Yes, it's a 3. Put the 3 into capture group 1. Are the the next two digits also a 3. No, the first one is, but the second one is a 5. No match.
4. ... similar no match for the rest of them.

Regex #2

1. [Same as regex1 step 1] Look at the first character, is it a digit? Yes, it's a 4.  Put the 4 into capture group 1. Now look at the next character.  Is it a 4. No, it's a 3.  No match. Move on to character #2.
2. Put 2nd character (3) into capture group 1.  The next 2 characters are the same, try to consume them all, then start the lookahead - is it a 3.  No, it's a 5, no match.  But now we can backtrack to the `\1+` and consume only one 3 instead of 2. Move forward again to the first lookahead. Is it a 3? Yes. Back up and do the second lookahead. Is it also a 3? Yes, and we're done, **SUCCESS**.

What gets matched are the first two 3s.

#1 does not work because you require 4 of the same digits in a row (with the lookahead).

#2 works because you give it the option of 3 consecutive digits as a match.

Comment: By the way,  putting the exact same lookahead twice in a row is a complete waste of effort and tells me you do not understand lookaheads very well.  If the first one matches, then you will back up to the same place the first one started, scan the exact same characters over again using the same logic and match it again.   Pointless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer but i put 1 lookbehind and 1 lookahead, what do you mean?